# Ignite caching/querying taking too much time

Tags: ignite, gridgain

I m trying to adopt ignite to resolve one of my needs by implementing an in memory data grid

Right know I m using a 3rd persistence read/write through mechanism to fetch data from my oracle db, in my topology I m using a single node in my activated cluster that are hosted in a VM having 8G ram and 120 G hdd.

my node is using local storage with a on-heap memory of 2G and 50G off-heap memory, all this with eviction and swapping enabled

```
DataStorageConfiguration dataStorageCfg = new DataStorageConfiguration();

DataRegionConfiguration dataRegionCfg = new DataRegionConfiguration();



// 2G initial size (RAM).
dataRegionCfg.setInitialSize(2L * 1024 * 1024 * 1024);

// 40 GB max size (RAM).
dataRegionCfg.setMaxSize(40L * 1024 * 1024 * 1024);

// Enabling RANDOM_LRU eviction for this region.
dataRegionCfg.setPageEvictionMode(DataPageEvictionMode.RANDOM_LRU);

//dataRegionCfg.setPersistenceEnabled(true);
final String swapPath ="/opt/ignite/swap";

dataRegionCfg.setSwapPath(swapPath);

dataStorageCfg.setDefaultDataRegionConfiguration(dataRegionCfg);

cfg.setDataStorageConfiguration(dataStorageCfg);
```

Caching this on my machine is taking too much time

my swap folder is about 13G when caching comes to end
concerning my SQL query there is no response

the same query in my tools takes 1min45s to respond but using ignite cache query method doesn't respond and doesn't trow any kind of error or exception

```
SqlFieldsQuery sqlQuery;
FieldsQueryCursor<List<?>> queryCursor;
Iterator<List<?>> resultIt;

System.out.println(">>> All caches loaded! in : " + total + " ms");

System.out.println("---------------------------------------------- ");
System.out.println("---------------------------------------------- ");
System.out.println("---------------------------------------------- ");

System.out.println("\\n \\n \\n ");
System.out.println("---------------------------------------------- ");
System.out.println("---------------------------------------------- ");
System.out.println("---------------------------------------------- ");

System.out.println("Checking join query POC first run");

start = System.currentTimeMillis();
sqlQuery = new SqlFieldsQuery(sql);
queryCursor = ignite.cache("MInoutlineCache").query(sqlQuery);
System.out.println("query result size is : "+queryCursor.getAll().size());

end = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
total += end;
```

M I well using ignite? is using ignite in a one node fashion useful, or I was meant to build clusters with lot of nodes in a partitioned strategy ?

the number of lines cached is 10 million line
is there another way to achieve a good in memory data-grid in my context using the 3rd persistence strategy.

There is lot of question in this question I m sorry

**NB:** I m using the grid gain console to generate my configuration
I m also updating my caching schema names as public to execute query directly

Here is the query

```
 SELECT bp.name,
    CF.documentno,
    CF.MOVEMENTDATE,
    CF.m_product_id AS M_PRODUCT_ID,
    CF.product,
    CF.xx_lignegratuite,
    CF.m_attributesetinstance_id,
    CASE
      WHEN cf.isreturntrx='Y'
      THEN - CF.qtyentered
      ELSE CF.qtyentered
    END AS qtyentered,
    CF.discount,
    CF.DOCSTATUS,
    CF.ISRETURNTRX,
    CF.XX_REWARDAMT,
    CF.OperID,
    CF.clientId,
    CASE
      WHEN cf.xx_lignegratuite='N'
      THEN
        CASE
          WHEN cf.isreturntrx='Y'
          THEN             -cf.prixVente*cf.qtyentered* (1-(cf.discount/100))
          ELSE cf.prixVente*cf.qtyentered* (1-(cf.discount/100))
        END
      ELSE 0
    END AS totalline,
    CASE
      WHEN cf.XX_StartegicalProduct='Y'
      THEN (
        CASE
          WHEN cf.xx_lignegratuite='N'
          THEN
            CASE
              WHEN cf.isreturntrx='Y'
              THEN             -cf.prixVente*cf.qtyentered* (1-(cf.discount/100))
              ELSE cf.prixVente*cf.qtyentered* (1-(cf.discount/100))
            END
          ELSE 0
        END)
      ELSE 0
    END AS totallineStar,
    CASE
      WHEN cf.xx_lignegratuite='N'
      THEN
        CASE
          WHEN cf.typevente='W'
          THEN
            CASE
              WHEN cf.isreturntrx='Y'
              THEN                -(cf.XX_REWARDAMT/nb_doc)
              ELSE cf.XX_REWARDAMT/nb_doc
            END
          ELSE 0
        END
      ELSE 0
    END AS totalreward,
    CF.XX_StartegicalProduct,
    CF.SALESREP_ID,
    CF.C_DOCTYPE_ID,
    CF.AD_ORG_ID,
    CF.ad_orgtrx_id,
    CF.xx_laboratory_id,
    bp.c_bpartner_id,
    CF.nb_doc,
    CF.rate,
    CF.poste_id,
    CF.SalesRepTier_poste_id,
    CF.recSupr,
    CF.recSupr_poste_id,
    (SELECT Objectif_CA_oper
    FROM c_bpartner
    WHERE issalesrep ='Y'
    AND isemployee   ='Y'
    AND c_bpartner_id=CF.SalesRepTier
    ) AS ObjectifOp,
    (SELECT Objectif_CA_oper
    FROM c_bpartner
    WHERE issalesrep ='Y'
    AND isemployee   ='Y'
    AND c_bpartner_id=CF.SalesRepTier_poste_id
    ) AS ObjectifOp_poste_id,
    CASE
      WHEN cf.ISRETURNTRX='Y'
      THEN              -cf.QTYENTERED*prixRevient
      ELSE cf.QTYENTERED*prixRevient
    END AS consomation
  FROM
    (SELECT i.documentno,
      i.MOVEMENTDATE,
      p.m_product_id,
      p.name AS product,
      ol.xx_lignegratuite,
      il.m_attributesetinstance_id,
      il.qtyentered,
      ol.discount,
      i.DOCSTATUS,
      i.isreturntrx,
      ol.XX_REWARDAMT,
      i.C_BPartner_ID AS clientId,
      (SELECT u.C_BPARTNER_ID FROM AD_User u WHERE u.AD_User_ID = i.SALESREP_ID
      ) AS OperID,
      (SELECT ai.Valuenumber
      FROM M_AttributeInstance ai
      INNER JOIN M_Attribute a
      ON (ai.M_Attribute_ID             =a.M_Attribute_ID
      AND a.IsInstanceAttribute         ='Y')
      WHERE ai.M_AttributeSetInstance_ID=il.m_attributesetinstance_id
      AND a.Name                        ='Prix Vente'
      ) AS prixVente,
      (SELECT ai.Valuenumber
      FROM M_AttributeInstance ai
      INNER JOIN M_Attribute a
      ON (ai.M_Attribute_ID             =a.M_Attribute_ID
      AND a.IsInstanceAttribute         ='Y')
      WHERE ai.M_AttributeSetInstance_ID=il.m_attributesetinstance_id
      AND a.Name                        ='Prix Revient'
      ) AS prixRevient,
      (SELECT ai.Valuenumber
      FROM M_AttributeInstance ai
      INNER JOIN M_Attribute a
      ON (ai.M_Attribute_ID             =a.M_Attribute_ID
      AND a.IsInstanceAttribute         ='Y')
      WHERE ai.M_AttributeSetInstance_ID=il.m_attributesetinstance_id
      AND a.Name                        ='Fournisseur'
      ) AS Fournisseur,
      XX_StartegicalProduct,
      i.SALESREP_ID,
      i.C_DOCTYPE_ID,
      i.AD_ORG_ID,
      (SELECT o.AD_ORGTRX_ID
      FROM c_order o
      WHERE i.c_order_id=o.c_order_id
      ) AS ad_orgtrx_id,
      p.xx_laboratory_id,
      lt.rate,
      --COUNT(*) over (partition BY il.c_orderline_id) AS nb_doc,
      (
      SELECT COUNT(*)
      FROM m_inoutline ill
      WHERE ill.c_orderline_id=il.c_orderline_id
      )               AS nb_doc,
      ol.type         AS typevente,
      bpl.salesrep_id AS poste_id,
      (SELECT u.c_bpartner_id FROM AD_User u WHERE u.AD_User_ID = i.salesrep_id
      ) AS SalesRepTier,
      (SELECT u.c_bpartner_id FROM AD_User u WHERE u.AD_User_ID = bpl.salesrep_id
      ) AS SalesRepTier_poste_id,
      (SELECT u.XX_RecSupervisor_ID FROM AD_User u WHERE u.AD_User_ID=i.SALESREP_ID
      ) AS recSupr,
      (SELECT u.XX_RecSupervisor_ID
      FROM AD_User u
      WHERE u.AD_User_ID=bpl.salesrep_id
      ) AS recSupr_poste_id
    FROM m_inoutline il
    INNER JOIN m_inout i
    ON il.m_inout_id=i.m_inout_id
    INNER JOIN c_orderline ol
    ON ol.c_orderline_id=il.c_orderline_id
    INNER JOIN m_product p
    ON p.m_product_id=il.m_product_id
    INNER JOIN C_Bpartner bpl
    ON (bpl.c_bpartner_id=i.c_bpartner_id)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN xx_listetauxvaleur lt
    ON p.xx_listetauxvaleur_id = lt.xx_listetauxvaleur_id
    WHERE i.issotrx            ='Y'
      --AND p.m_attributeset_id   IS NOT NULL
    AND il.movementqty<>0
    ) CF
  LEFT OUTER JOIN c_bpartner bp
  ON (CF.Fournisseur=bp.c_bpartner_id)
  ORDER BY bp.name,
    documentno;
```

Comment: Can you show your query? Can you show your table structure?

Comment: @alamar I updated the question, in oracle this query takes it time about 2 min max
every table is cached, I m watching using the visor that my caching works (but too much time consumption) I have a guess that this is related to disk writing but why the query result is not responding even after 45 min or more
I already tested the quering of large dataset (3 million line) in one cache the respond was quick but without swipe or eviction.

Comment: this query is a hot collection of datas that we use every day every hour in our workflow, m I then forced to upgrade my ram capacity ? there is no other solutions ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a lot of joins in your statement. Are you sure that you have indexes on all the fields present in those joins? I think it would take a lot of optimization until this one will perform.

I also recommend getting rid of swap since this is an outdated feature and its performance implications are not known.

If you expect to outperform Oracle on a single node when doing multiple joins, this is also not going to happen.

Comment: for indexes yes, I m using the grid-gain console Import from database and it is reading well all keys/indexes and fields.
if not using swap what do you suggest
last and funny outperforming oracle in single node is not going to happen and I will report this for the 3rd time this week. thanks for proving that I m right

Comment: I don't think that Web Console will create correct indexes for you.

Answer (score 1):

Consider general performance tips that should answer most of your questions and issues:
https://www.gridgain.com/docs/latest/perf-troubleshooting-guide/general-perf-tips

To achieve maximum performance you need to keep an entire data set in RAM. If there is a lack of resources then consider Ignite native persistence instead of the swap storage.